# Structure Database employee leave (vacation) customizable per day of a whole year

Tags: database

For a project I need to build a vacation management system where Business and Employee can ask/give/accept vacation day + see how many days there are left etc.

The problem that I have, people work irregular. So sometimes saturday, etc. So I want to make basic schedule profiles and also let businesses be able to customize each day of the whole year.

How do I structure the Database Tables?

Do I add all the days from each year? O do I make a colum with the data?

Could somebody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a `calendar-table` and a `leaves-table`. The calendar-table would have all days with a primary key on the `day` and extra columns for business-defined data. The leaves-table would have a composite primary key on `day` and `employee id`, the foreign key on 'day' to `calendar-table` and with extra columns for leave-related data.

With a left join from `calendar-table` to `leaves-table` you can get both the business reports (how many leave-days are recorded in a specific day, week, month, etc.) and the employee reports.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to draw it and try it out!!